# AngularJs code to navigate to another page in buttonclick

Tags: angularjs

AngularJs code to navigate to another page on a button click event. I have catch the button click event but cannot navigate to another page.
The following is my code:
HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app/home.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

      <button ng-click="clicked()">Click me!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

And the javascript file is:

```
var VLogin = angular.module('myapp',[]);

VLogin.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.clicked = function(){   

        $location.path('/test.html');
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me resolve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546218/angularjs-form-is-not-submitting-data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try like as shown below...

In html,

```
 <button ng-click="clicked()">Click</button>
```

In JS,

```
 $scope.clicked = function(){
       window.location = "#/test.html";
 }
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: SDK: Yes its work for me.. But in the path i have to change like this : window.location = "../www/index.html";

Comment: dont forget to accept this answer if you find it useful:-)

Comment: hi, I want the button to redirect to another component's html page. how can that be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can use $location.path('/newPageUrl') to navigate to new page.

Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more information on $location.

Edit: 
    The correct controller code would be (after adding $location as a dependency):-

```
VLogin.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',function($scope, $location) {

$scope.clicked = function(){   

    $location.path('/test.html');
}
```

}]);

Comment: Abhishek Jain: I have used the $location.path('/newPageUrl') code but it's not working for me.

Comment: You have to pass $location service to controller

Comment: But use absolute path redirection with $window Here you have it: http://plnkr.co/edit/nClPD7mFdF4Rz2VmhZSJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to another page **onclick** I suggest using good old 'link'

```
<a href="/another-page">Go to another page</a>
```

Unless you have to do something before redirection than use $location service proposed by [Abhishek Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098338/1223357)

Comment: Teq1:I want to navigate inside button click event function.

Comment: @BibinJose using my solution you do :) But as I mentioned use good old `href` unless you have to do something before redirection than use `$location` service which is better to test.

Comment: @Teq1 can't put a inside or outside of button - htmlangular validation fails